# Weird graphical bug appears in a multiple-layered parallax image

Tags: html, css, parallax, astrojs

I am currently building a section that has a parallax scrolling effect with multiple layers of PNG images.

link: https://albertyhu.github.io/tutorial/content/

The 3D effect can be observable while scrolling down the page.

If you are on a Chrome, Opera, or Edge browser, you will notice that there is a graphical issue at the bottom of the image as you scroll down. A rectangular hole appears and it partially obstructs the bottom part of the image. For some reason, this issue doesn't appear on Firefox.

I built the image with HTML and CSS. The images are created by cutting out the original landscape image and creating multiple layers from those components on Photoshop.

The following parallax image is built with the following code:

```
<section
    class = "sectionStyle"
>
    <header class="header">
        <img src={Layer1} alt = "layer1" class ="layer1Style" />
        <img src={Layer2} alt = "layer2" class ="layer2Style" />
        <img src={Layer3} alt = "layer3" class ="layer3Style" />
        <img src={Layer4} alt = "layer4" class ="layer4Style" />
        <img src={Layer5} alt = "layer5" class ="layer5Style" />
        <h1
            class="text-center text-2xl font-bold"
        >Welcome!</h1>
    </header>
    <div class = "bg-black h-fit text-white text-base py-10 ">
        <div
            class="w-11/12 mx-auto"
        >
            <p>//written content</p>
//skip
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This can be viewed in the following Github page:
https://github.com/Albertyhu/tutorial/blob/main/src/components/parallaxHero.astro

The following style sheet is used to add style and create the parallax effect:

https://github.com/Albertyhu/tutorial/blob/main/src/styles/parallaxHeroStyle.css

I appreciate any help I can get from someone who has an idea of what is causing the rectangular hole to appear at the bottom of the parallax image as the user scrolls down.

Edit:
I created another page that has a parallax image. It follows the same HTML mark up format and CSS styling as the previous one. Unfortunately, it displays the same problem with the rectangular hole that appears on the site when it is viewed with Chrome, Opera and Edge:

Link to view: https://albertyhu.github.io/tutorial/los-angeles/

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the issue is that the file size for the images are too large. Once I compressed the sizes of all layers, the graphical glitch no longer appears.